# refactor legacy code, extracting small interface from a giant one with a small implementation

Tags: oop, refactoring

I have a large piece of code (legacy) which knows to connect to an external service lets say connects to skype and bring its availability, the way its doing this (this is how it works its for the sake of the example). is

```
SkypeAvailabilityManager.java

.init
.start
.stop
.connect
.disconnect
.keepAlive
.updateStatus
```

(lets assume for the example that all methods need to be public and someone calls them).
Now there is a huge piece of code (huge legacy code which calls all above methods).

Now I need to have either synchronizing with skype or with some other service lets say its `MessengerB`

However with messengerB i don't need the init, start, connect, etc, i only need the updateStatus method.

So I thought of this refactor (which does not yet sound fine to me i'll explain why

```
Interface: ExternalStatusFetcher
```

methods of it:

```
.updateStatus
```

Now the legacy code calls the above methods of .init .start .stop .connect in many many places, however the new MessengerStatusUpdaterImpl I need to add only needs .updateStatus and i want to reuse the .updateStatus of the skype implementation because i want to reuse code.

so my limitations:

1. Reuse SkypeAvailabilityManager.java
2. Legacy code calls .start .stop ... from many places in code I don't what to change that this is a huge legacy.
3. I want a common interface meaning in my code I want to treat both impl the same way but so client would either call all the methods or only part of them i do not know until impelemntation is actually initialized with the real implemenation.

what would be a good refactor of it?
If my container class holds an interface that holds all methods this owuld be nice, however my second implemenation does not need all the methods, so i'm a little mixed up what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the calling code I would go for:

1. Create an interface with all the methods. With this you are explicitly stating what you implicitly have in your code, that is the contract between the legacy software and your messenger(s).
2. Make `MessengerB` implement the interface, where all the methods except for `updateStatus` are just no-ops (ie. empty methods that do nothing).
3. If you are going to have many of these messengers implementations, you can create an abstract class that implements the interface and where all the methods are no-ops and then create a subclass for each specific messenger that overrides the appropriate methods.

IMHO this is a good first step, mainly because it captures well the current code status, states pretty clear what do you need to implement to create a new messenger and can serve as a basis if you want to later refactor the legacy code.

HTH